# Call code from code behind on page load in ASP.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am simly trying to call the code from a code behind immediateky, as soon as the page loads.

How can I accomplish this? I tried making an invisible button and then tried clicking that on load, but that is not working for me. Hoping there is a simpler way.

This is the code behind. Filename is `CodeBehind.aspx.cs`:

```
    public partial class DoTheThing: InjectablePageBase
    {
        private string GetURL(Object sender, EventArgs e){
             // RUN MY CODE
        }
    }
```

And this is the relevant part of the `.aspx` file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="CodeBehind.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.GuideMe.DoTheThing" MasterPageFile="~/Theme/Framework.Master"%>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContentPlaceHolder">
<script Language="JavaScript">
    window.onload = function() { document.querySelector('#invisibleGuideMeBtn').click() };
</script>

<div>
    <a id="invisibleGuideMeBtn" href="#" onclick="<%= GetURL %>" target="_self"  runat="server">The Link</a>
    <%-- <asp:Button ID="invisibleGuideMeBtn" Text="Edit" onclick="GetURL" CssClass="btn btn-primary"/> --%>
    <%-- <asp:LinkButton id="invisibleGuideMeBtn" Text="" OnClientClick="GetURL" runat="server"/> --%>
    <%-- <u><b><asp:LinkButton OnClick="GetGuideMeURL" runat="server">Click here</asp:LinkButton></b></u> --%>

</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Above are 4 different ways I tried clicking a button/link to call the code behind. I either get the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click')
    at window.onload
```

OR the error:
`The function GetURL cannot be found`

Comment: Did you check to make sure that the ID of the object in the DOM is what you expect it to be? Web Forms by default modifies the ID that you specify for its controls in order to prevent collisions. Are you new to Web Forms? Is that a decision in your control? It's very strange to learn Web Forms in 2022: it's a dead framework

Comment: Yes, I am new to it. Given this task at work and not familiar with it. I checked the DOM, you were right. The value was different. Still not working though. It looks to me that the function in the code behind is just not being seen because I even tried this JQuery and no luck ```    $( document ).ready(function() {
        GetURL();
    });
```

Comment: You can't just provide the method name and invoke it. That's not how that works. Your button approach could work. What went wrong with that approach, once you got the correct ID and used JavaScript to click it?

Comment: So with the correct ID, I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at VM27989 GuideMe.aspx:1151:123)
    at window.onload` and this that line, so I don't get the error: `window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('Master_PageContent_invisibleGuideMeBtn').click() };  `

Comment: Forget all the JavaScript for me a minute. Make your button visible. Then click it. Does that succeed? Start simple.

Comment: Your method is private and returns a string. That's not the correct signature for a button's click event handler. Start with a basic Web Forms tutorial to learn how the event system works.

Comment: And why not just put the code in the page load event?

Comment: @albert I tried that as well. No matter how I try, the code behind function is not defined apparently.

Comment: after the page loads, and you NOW again run some code, (say click a button), then the page re-loads, and now after page load, your code is to run again? And again???? I mean, running code after page load means a page -post back, and re-load of the page again, which then means your code would run again and again, right? So, you need some criteria as to WHICH time the code is to run after page load, since any run of code behind will trigger a re-load of the page, and trigger your code to run again, right????

Comment: (and when  said to put the code in on-load - I meant ONLY code behind run code in page load, not after page loads, since if your code is to run after page load, it will then cause the page to re-load and then trigger your code that supposed to run after the page loads, but that will trigger a page load, and cause the code to run again, right?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error once and the following fixed it, not sure if it'll work for you.

I used <%#CSCodeName() %> this format to get the code behind and sometimes I'd have to add a semi-colon like this <%#CSCodeName(); %>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

so, the page is to load, then display and THEN we are to click a button and run some code.

but, that means the page will re-load, and after page load, your code runs again then right?

so, there has to be additional information to correctly answer this question. You can certainly with ease trigger some code, and even have such code click a hidden button to run your code stub in code behind. But that of course will cause the page to post back, re-load, and now we back to after the page loads - which it just did, we going to run the code again?

So, what criteria are you to use after page load to run, or not run the code you want again? Without this information, then after page load, we click that hidden button, and then page will load again, and after page load, the code will click the button again and again, then right?